# How to create reviews for user comments?

Tags: 8, nodes, users, rating

I want use user review for my content. For example they can send their comment in my content and review in comment ( with fivestar field ).

Five star and other module not work in drupal 8.

Comment: Well if you want 5 stars as you says in my answer you will need to help a little in the migration as is not possible at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario is not very encouraging for Drupal 8 in voting modules at this time, but you can check some modules that can help you:

[Votingapi Widgets](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi_widgets)

> A flexible field based Voting System based on
>   https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi .

[Like Button](https://www.drupal.org/project/likebtn)

> Add a Like button to Drupal content and comments! Get instant
>   statistics and insights! Sort content by likes!

[Star Rating](https://www.drupal.org/project/starrating)

> Star Rating is a simple module that provides star rating field and
>   display formatter using Drupal 7's Field Type API.

Comment: Thanks but I want add 5star to my content.

Comment: @RobinSon the first module that I recommend https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi_widgets allow you to add a star widget, can you check the project page? And tell me if this solve your problem?

Comment: @RobinSon I just see that we have a Drupal 8 version for https://www.drupal.org/project/starrating take a look in the project page, and I updated my answer.